# before_destroy and dependent destroy not firing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, callback

I have the following model associations:

```
class Slider < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :featured_happening, :as => :featured_item, :dependent => :destroy   
  before_destroy :destroy_featured_happening
  after_create :create_featured_happening
end

class FeaturedHappening < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :featured_item, :polymorphic => true
end
```

When I destroy a `Slider` object I thought the `dependent => :destroy` would automatically destroy the `featured_item` but it does not.

Slider controller

```
 def destroy    
    slider = Slider.find(params[:id])
    slider.delete
    render(:status => :ok, :nothing => true )
  end
```

So then I tried a callback with `before_destroy` to manually delete the `featured_item` when a slider object is destroyed and nothing is getting called.

How can I get the `featured_item` to be deleted when I delete a slider object? Using Rails 3.2.

Comment: How are you deleting the `Slider` instance?

Comment: def destroy    
    slider = Slider.find(params[:id])
    slider.delete
    render(:status => :ok, :nothing => true )
  end

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You just observed the difference between `delete` and `destroy`. In your controller you call

```
slider.delete
```

which will just execute a SQL `DELETE` but will not call any callbacks. That's why in normal cases you want to use `destroy` instead. It will fetch the object (if necessary), call the callbacks including recursive destroys and only then deletes the object from the database.

See the documentation for [delete](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-delete) and [destroy](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-destroy) for more information.

Comment: Geez, well noted. I always thought one was an alias of the other. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Ensure that you are calling `Slider#destroy` in order to trigger callbacks. `Slider#delete` will simply delete the record without calling them.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Slider < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :featured_happening,  :dependent => :destroy  
end

class FeaturedHappening < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :featured_item
end
```

If your code was simple like above in which there is simple relationship. Then with the deletion of slider, Feature Happing will be delete with the deletion of slider. But in your case the relationship is polymorphic. In feature happing table in DB the abject_id will be the id of slider or may be some other class. Therefore the dependent :destroy not working. So you should need to delete it with before_destroy callback in which you first retrieve the records and then destroy them